# Best way to instantiate a class with a private object that needs instantiating as well

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I have a class `MyClass` that I want to instantiate and which contains a private  property `ObjectRepository` that I want to instantiate when the constructor of `MyClass` is called.

```
public MyClass
{
    private ObjectRepository _objectRepository;

    public MyClass()
    {

    }
}
```

`MyClass` is instantiated to be added in a list:

```
objects.Add(new MyClass());
```

What is the cleanest way to do this following the SOLID priciples?

----EDIT----

What I also forgot to mention is that when I write unit tests for `MyClass` I want to be able to mock `ObjectRepository`. That is not possible when `ObjectRepository` is instantiated from the constructor of `MyClass`, because no reference to `_objectRepository` is available from the test.

Comment: if `_objectRepository` is *private*, then creating `_objectRepository` instance is a private affair of `MyClass`; we can create an instance in the constructor: `public MyClass() {_objectRepository = new ObjectRepository();}`

Comment: What exactly is MyClass going to be doing?

Comment: @Bunnynut but if you make _objectRepository available it begins useless to be private, just make it public, no?

Answer (score 5):

For this, you need to look at the D in SOLID: *Dependency Inversion*.

`MyClass` needs an instance of `ObjectRepository` to do whatever it does; it has a *dependency* on `ObjectRepository`. Under the Dependency Inversion principle, it should instead depend on an abstraction, rather than a concrete type. In C#, the usual way to do this would be with an interface, something like `IObjectRepository`, which has all the methods on it that `MyClass` needs, but nothing else. It could also be done with an abstract base class, but that's less common.

Of course, if you're depending on an interface, you don't know about the concrete type that implements it, so you can't instantiate it. This is fine; you just have to be provided with an instance instead.

```
public MyClass
{
    private IObjectRepository _objectRepository;

    public MyClass(IObjectRepository objectRepository)
    {
        _objectRepository = objectRepository;
    }
}
```

Now, when you create an instance of `MyClass`, you have to provide it with something that implements `IObjectRepository`.

```
objects.Add(new MyClass(new ObjectRepository()));
```

In many cases, this is enough. However, for large object graphs it can be laborious and repetitive to create everything manually like this. The usual way to solve this is with a dependency injection service like an IoC container. IoC stands for *inversion of control*, because you're inverting the creation of things. Instead of instantiating what's at the top and having each thing create the things that it needs, an IoC container starts from the bottom, creating the thing that's needed, and then using that to create the thing that depends on it, and so on. An example of how you might use this is as follows:

```
var container = new SomeIoCContainer();
container.For<IObjectRepository>().Use<ObjectRepository>();

var myClass = container.Resolve<MyClass>();
```

*(Example syntax; this differs from one IoC container to the next, but they're usually something like this.)*

In many cases, you'll find that IoC containers can be integrated into your applications, which means that you don't even need to explicitly call your container to resolve things. For example, ASP.NET is built to do this, so once your container is configured, you can just add constructor parameters to your controllers and the framework will use the container to provide them for you.

The advantages of this approach:

- If you want to test something that happens inside of `MyClass`, you can simply give it a fake version of `IObjectRepository` that doesn't do anything complicated, so that you can set up your tests with much less work, and you know that your tests on `MyClass` won't be affected by unrelated things that might happen inside of `ObjectRepository`. You could do this by having a separate container set up for tests, but usually it's easier to do this by hand - you're only testing one thing, and your mock dependencies shouldn't depend on anything.
- As your application grows and becomes more complicated, you don't have to worry about how to create all the components that things depend on - you simply tell your IoC container what they are, and it will take care of creating things.
- It's much easier if you ever need to change how one of the dependencies work. For example, if you have a `DatabaseObjectRepository` that gets objects from a SQL database, and you want to swap it for a `WebClientObjectRepository` that gets the objects from a web service instead, you just implement the same interface and change that one line where you told the container what to use for `IObjectRepository`, and it will swap every usage in your application for you.

Comment: excellent answer. If I was there first, I'd have written something like that too. Especially because he wants to be able to test this (propably Unit-Tests) he needs to be able to mock an interface, as this is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize from constructor?

```
public MyClass
{
    private ObjectRepository _objectRepository;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _objectRepository = new ObjectRepository();
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, this way I can't mock `_objectRepository` in my unit test?

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward.
You will initialize the private instance within the classe's constructor, passing any arguments needed for your private instance throught the class constructor, like so:

```
public MyClass
{
    private ObjectRepository _objectRepository;

    public MyClass(string connString)
    {
        // if your ObjectRepository for example requires a connection string param
        _objectRepository = new ObjectRepository(connString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the constructor doesn't accept parameters and `_objectRepository` is to be assigned a value which doesn't depend on the context in which the call is made, e.g. there is no validation to be performed, then simply:

```
public MyClass()
{
   _objectRepository = new ObjectRepository(); 
}
```

EDIT: Based on the new information OP gave in his edit, I find Anaximander's answer to be the best one.